# How to perform action when a click happens outside of specified elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up a system so that when a user clicks, if that click did not originate from within a specified div then a function should be fired that will do something with that div. Basically more when a user clicks outside of a div i want to hide it, but the problem is that i have a few elements that i want to do this with, so event.stopPropagation doesn't work very well.

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
e = !e ? window.event.srcElement : e.target;

if ($('#toppanel div#panel').not(e.id).is(':visible')) { $('.dashboardNav .addWidget').click(); }
if ($('#TrackRibbon').not(e.id).is(':visible')) { $('.dashboardNav #openRibbon').click(); }
if ($('.subnav').not(e.id).is(':visible')) { $('.subnav').hide(); }
}
```

but this doesn't work as i want either yet, it does somewhat, but i have multiple .subnav on the page and with this you can open all of them without the others closing.

any ideas on how to accomplish a goal like this would be greatly appreciated, also if i didnt explain well enough just let me know.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not? You seem to be but didn't tag the question as such, and also if you are using jQuery why not use it to setup your event handler?

Comment: I am using jquery and i accidentally hit enter to soon when adding the tags and didnt get to add that one. And im not sure how i would setup the handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how i managed to accomplish most of what I wanted. I think with a few tweaks it will be good.

```
    $(document).click(function (e) {

        var closables = ["#TrackRibbon", '#toppanel', '.subnav', '#Mailbox'];

        var toggles = ['#openRibbon', '.addWidget', '.topnav > li', '#MailboxToggle'];

        var skip = -1;
        e = !e ? window.event.srcElement : e.target;

        for (var j = 0; j < toggles.length; j++) {
            if ($(e).parent(toggles[j]).length > 0 || $(e).is(toggles[j])) {
                skip = j; continue;
            }
        }

        for (var k = 0; k < closables.length; k++) {
            $(closables[k]).each(function (i) {
                if (skip !== k) {
                    if ($(this).has($(e)).length === 0 && $(this).is(':visible')) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The only part that doesn't work quite right is the '.subnav' which there can potentially be a lot of. So if anyone has any suggestions to improve let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).hasClass('dontTriggerThisFunction')) { return; }

  doTheStuffWeWantToDo();
});
```

Comment: only for non-dynamically added items, but I'm thinking that might be the best he can do

Comment: @Adam Rackis - That should work for dynamically added items too.